# Compilation error on Arduino sketch with ros_lib

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to run the ros_lib HelloWorld program on an Arduino Uno, but got the following error:

`In file included from /home/turtlebot/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ros.h:38:0,
                 from button_example.cpp:5:
/home/turtlebot/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ros/node_handle.h: In member function ‘void ros::NodeHandle_::logdebug(const char*)’:
/home/turtlebot/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ros/node_handle.h:414:13: error: ‘DEBUG’ is not a member of ‘rosserial_msgs::Log’`

**Background:** I have groovy installed on my netbook . I used the instructions [here](http://ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup) with the rosbuild option to build rosserial_arduino on the netbook. I then moved the ros_lib libraries to the relevant Arduino folder and tried to run the example sketches on the Arduino.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60097/compilation-error-on-arduino-sketch-with-ros_lib/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2013-04-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Balakumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/5050/balakumar/) on 2013-07-17**:
Did you find a solution? I am stuck with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Go to sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/rosserial_msgs and open Log.h using a text editor.
Rplace ROSDEBUG with DEBUG save the file and your done.

---

Originally posted by [balakumar-s](https://answers.ros.org/users/5452/balakumar-s/) with karma: 137 on 2013-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0